# How to Scrape data from Indiegogo.com in google sheets via IMPORTXML formula

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, scrape

I am trying to take a funding number from Indiegogo.com via IMPORTXML function without any luck.

I have used this code to scrape data from Kickstarter and it worked.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/pavlyukovskyy/lego-compatible-screenless-coding-for-ages-3-6", "//span[@class='ksr-green-500']")
```

However, it doesn't work for indiegogo.com. I am trying this for indiegogo:

```
=IMPORTXML(https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/zlight-smart-bedroom-hub/", "//span[@class='data-v-3acff91c']")
```

I've also tried

```
=IMPORTXML(https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/zlight-smart-bedroom-hub/", "//span[@class='basicsGoalProgress-amountSold']")
```

Both versions didn't give any result

I need to show funding sum in google sheets. 
Please see the screenshot https://www.screencast.com/t/h2ZwVsXr33

Here is the URL https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/zlight-smart-bedroom-hub

Comment: Your second and third statements appear to be missing an opening quote mark for the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't scrape data from that page using importxml function because the content on the page is rendered using javascript and importxml can't import javascript rendered webpages.

Easy way to check whether a web content is rendered via javascript is to deactivate javascript. So the data which you get after deactivating javascript is the data which you can import in Google Sheet using importxml.

**To Deactivate Javascript on some specific page.**

1. Open that webpage in Google Chrome.
2. In the address bar, before web address, you will see an icon (lock or i etc), click on that then click on site settings and then in "Permissions" section, select "block" option for javascript.
3. After that simply refresh the page.